# How to set arbitrary version number for uploaded content?

Tags: java, transactions, alfresco, versioning, alfresco-webscripts

I am developing the content uploader that represents a [Surf WebScript](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/dev-extensions-share-surf-web-scripts.html). Perhaps it would be more correct to say "updater", because the content already exists in the repository, but may not have `cm:versionable` aspect. I need to update this content and set the correct version number (arbitrary, for example).

I noticed that the first upload always gets the number `1.0`.

For example, suppose that content model does not have the `cm:versionable` aspect. I can add it by this way and specify the version number that I need (`1.1`):

```
if(!nodeService.hasAspect(nodeRef, QNAME_ASPECT_VERSIONABLE)) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {
        {
            put(QNAME_VERSION_LABEL, INITIAL_UPLOADED_VERSION); // 1.1
            put(QNAME_AUTO_VERSION, false);
        }
    };
    nodeService.addAspect(nodeRef, QNAME_ASPECT_VERSIONABLE, map);
    // SKIPPED
```

Constants that I used:

```
final String NS_ALF_CONTENT_MODEL  = "http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0";
final String ASPECT_CM_VERSIONABLE = "versionable";
final String PROP_VERSION_LABEL    = "versionLabel";
final String PROP_AUTO_VERSION     = "autoVersion";
final String INITIAL_UPLOADED_VERSION = "1.1";

final QName QNAME_ASPECT_VERSIONABLE = QName.createQName(NS_ALF_CONTENT_MODEL, ASPECT_CM_VERSIONABLE);
final QName QNAME_VERSION_LABEL = QName.createQName(NS_ALF_CONTENT_MODEL, PROP_VERSION_LABEL);  
final QName QNAME_AUTO_VERSION = QName.createQName(NS_ALF_CONTENT_MODEL, PROP_AUTO_VERSION);
```

When I debug this solution, I can see that I get the version that I need.

However, when I look at the node properties in the node browser, I see that `cm:versionLabel == 1.0`.

[image]

All the next uploads get the correct numbers, according to the logic that I use.

Why the version for the first upload is always have number 1.0 and how can I change this behaviour?..

[transaction level](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/api-wsdl-transaction.html) in my case: `<transaction>required</transaction>`

Comment: IIRC there's some bits that are hard-coded in Share, and some bits in the [VersionService method ensureVersioningEnabled](https://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/version/VersionService.html#ensureVersioningEnabled-org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef-java.util.Map-)...

Comment: If you're in Java, simplest is probably to call `ensureVersioningEnabled` and pass in a different initial version property

Comment: There's a behaviour bound to the versionable aspect, maybe check code for that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Patrik's](https://community.alfresco.com/people/patrik) advise is working ([Slothrop's](https://community.alfresco.com/people/slothrop) advice I didn't check). I've just set up the `initialVersion = false`.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
        put(QNAME_VERSION_LABEL, INITIAL_UPLOADED_VERSION); // 1.1
        put(QNAME_AUTO_VERSION, false);
        put(QNAME_INITIAL_VERSION, false);
    }
};

nodeService.addAspect(nodeRef, QNAME_ASPECT_CM_VERSIONABLE, map);
```

Now everything is Ok.

[image]

Thank's to @Gagravarr for his assistance.